# How to get text (or automate) from an external control in a Java application (AWT)?

Tags: java, c++, automation, awt

There is an application which is built in the SunAWTFrame class and, as you can guess, this is a strange world for the Windows API.

So I wonder, what should I do/use to get text from controls in a GUI built with this or automate them?

Is there some sort of API or library that can accomplish this and is suitable for work inside pure C++ or similiar language (not only Java)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is likely due to the Java GUI being a Swing GUI program (note that the MS Windows class for these GUI's -- at least I know for JFrames -- is "SunAWTFrame"), and since Swing uses light-weight components, not MS Windows native components, you won't easily be able to extract window information from them. I don't know of any easy way around this without the Java source code.

**Edit 1**
After a little Googling some I have found new information:

- Have you looked into using perhaps Java Monkey or Java Ferret?
- Or perhaps best of all, [Java Access Bridge](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136191.html) which *"is a technology that exposes the Java Accessibility API in a Microsoft Windows DLL, enabling Java applications and applets that implement the Java Accessibility API to be visible to assistive technologies on Microsoft Windows systems"*

Comment: Thanks for answer, i did try JAB but on the end it would only reveal data from a simple swing example app that is recommended inside JAB to test if JAB works. When i tried to use ferret or monkey(that comes with JAB) they wouldnt reveal anything from this SunAWTFrame gui, dont know why? Is JAB really only way to go around this? Also since you really need to copy, paste alot of files to install JAB this would mean that user who uses your app would have to do this harsh installation as well, no?

Answer (score 0):

java access bridge c# example:

[a link] https://github.com/jdog3/JavaAccessBridge.Net-Sample